# How can I structure my data for a recurrent event analysis?

Tags: r, survival-analysis

I'm quite new to R so maybe this seems simple but I can't figure it out. My data looks like Df and it needs to look like Df2:

```
Df <- data.frame(country = c("A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "B","B", "B", "B"),
                 year = c("1950", "1951", "1952", "1953", "1954", "1950", "1951", "1952", "1953"), 
                 start_year = c("NA", "1951", "1951", "NA", "1954", "1950", "NA", "1951", "1951"), 
                 end_year= c("NA", "NA", "1952", "NA", "1954", "1950", "NA", "NA", "NA"),
                 status = c(0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1),
                 treatment = c(10, "NA", 20, 5, "NA", "NA", 30, 100, 10))

Df2 <- data.frame(country = c("A", "A", "A", "A", "B","B", "B"),
                  time1 = c("1950", "1951", "1953", "1954", "1950", "1951", "1952"),
                  time2 = c("1951", "1953", "1954", "1955", "1951", "1952", "1954"),
                  status = c(0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1),
                  treatment = c(10, 20, 0, "NA", "NA", 30, 110))
```

The goal is to have it in a structure to do a PWP recurrent event analysis. Treatment in Df2 should be the sum of the treatment values of the intervals time1 to time 2.

Any ideas how I can get there? Thank you!

Comment: Why is B with `time1 = 1952` and `treatment = 110` but `A has `time1 = 1951` and `treatment = 20`. What's the logic here to choose `year` or `start_year`?

Comment: @Martin Gal `Treatment` in my data are funding amounts to women's organizations. And `year` is the year of the observation, or in other words the year when the funding was disbursed. `start_year` shows when a conflict started. Does it make sense now?

Answer (score 1):

You could use

```r
library(dplyr)

Df %>% 
  mutate(across(where(is.character), ~na_if(.x, "NA")),
         time1 = as.numeric(coalesce(start_year, year)),
         treatment = as.numeric(treatment)) %>% 
  group_by(country, time1, status) %>% 
  summarise(treatment = sum(treatment, na.rm = TRUE), .groups = "drop") %>% 
  group_by(country) %>% 
  mutate(time2 = lead(time1, default = last(time1) + 1)) %>% 
  select(country, time1, time2, status, treatment) %>% 
  ungroup()
```

to get

```r
# A tibble: 7 x 5
  country time1 time2 status treatment
  <chr>   <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>     <dbl>
1 A        1950  1951      0        10
2 A        1951  1953      1        20
3 A        1953  1954      0         5
4 A        1954  1955      1         0
5 B        1950  1951      1         0
6 B        1951  1951      0        30
7 B        1951  1952      1       110
```

That's not exactly your desired output (see my comment), but a start to solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
Df2 <- Df %>% mutate(episode = data.table::rleid(status))

library(tidyverse)
Df2 <- Df2 %>%
  arrange(country, year) %>%
  group_by(country, episode) %>%
  mutate(time1 = min(year))

Df2 <- Df2 %>%
  arrange(country, year) %>%
  group_by(country, episode) %>%
  mutate(time2 = (max(as.numeric(year) + 1)))
```

I have created an episode identifier and managed to identify `time1` and `time2` for each `episode`. Now, I still need to combine the rows grouped by `episode` so that there is one row per episode that shows the sum of `treatment`. Any ideas how to do that?